# Are sum types defined with UnboxedSums more efficient than plain enum?

Tags: performance, haskell, lazy-evaluation, algebraic-data-types

For example, here is simple Haskell enum data type:

```
data Bool = False | True
```

There's `-XUnboxedSums` extension since GHC-8.2.1 that allows to define sum types in more memory-efficient way. Here is a quote from documentation:

> In the degenerate case where all the alternatives have zero width, such as the `Bool`-like `(# (# #) | (# #) #)`, the unboxed sum layout only has an Int32 tag field (i.e., the whole thing is represented by an integer).

I wonder, whether this representation is more efficient than using simple plain Haskell enum data type?

And here is the full documentation:

- https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#unboxed-sums

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Semantics and Representation

The two types cannot be used interchangeable.

The type

```
data Bool = False | True
```

is a lifted type. This means that a variable `x :: Bool` can still be unevaluated (e.g. a thunk). It will therefore be represented as a pointer.

In contrast

```
(# (# #) | (# #) #)
```

is unlifted, and really can only have the two values, and will be represented as just a machine integer.

### Space efficiency

This does, however *not* mean that the latter is more space efficient: Because `True` and `False` are nullary constructors (they take no arguments), they exist once and for all in the static code of your program, and the pointers just point to them. So the cost is one machine word in all cases.

### Run time efficiency

The unboxed variant may be slightly more efficient than `Bool`:

- For `Bool`, the code first has to check *is this already evaluated?*, and then it can branch on which constructor it is.

  The branching is pretty efficient: The code does not have to follow the pointer for that: The “pointer tag” in the low few bits of the pointer address will indicate which constructor it is. There is a slight cost for masking the other bits, though.
- In the unboxed variant, well, it's just `0` or `1`, and no thunk check is needed.

## Things that might be true one day

**jberryman says**: as of Jan 2021 the following don't appear to be implemented yet, but this is how things might one day work.

### Unboxing in data types

If you define a data type like this

```
data Foo = Foo {-# UNPACK #-} !Bool
```

you should get exactly the same result as if you’d write

```
data Foo = Foo (# (# #) | (# #) #)
```

as that was the main purpose of the unboxed sum extension.

### Unboxing in functions

If you define a function that is strict in a `Bool` argument, e.g.

```
foo True = "Hello"
foo False = "World!"
```

then I could imagine (but did not check) that the compiler optimizes that into a *worker* that takes a `(# (# #) | (# #) #)` and a *wrapper* that takes care of the thunk-check. The wrapper might then inline in use-sites where `foo` is used, and everything might end up in terms of `(# (# #) | (# #) #)`.

### Conclusion

Don’t bother.

Comment: Currently (ghc 8.6.4), UNPACKing sums doesn't do anything.

Comment: GHC definitely doesn't use worker-wrapper for sums yet.

Comment: There is movement on unpacking sum types here: https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/merge_requests/4140

Comment: Additional info to follow development:
 https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues?label_name=UnboxedSums
https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/unpacked-sum-types

Comment: I wouldn't go so far as "don't bother". Even for products, GHC's worker-wrapper doesn't apply to (non-inlined) higher-order functions. So some manual unboxing will still be required even after support for sums is added.